# CSS3 Hover Background image not working in mozilla

Tags: html, css

I have implement the CSS3 in my application, if when I hover the li tag at the time the span tag image will be change with transition property. it was working good in chrome, but unfortunatly this effect(transition) is not working properly in firefox

Note: li inside span as a product image

I have tried the following HTML & css code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-col">
        <a href="javascript:void();">
            <span class="service-image">&nbsp;</span>
            <h4>Pest control</h4>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

CSS 

  .list-col .service-image {
     background: url("../images/service-08.png") no-repeat 0  0 transparent;
  } 

  .list-col:hover .service-image { 
     background: url("../images/service-08-hover.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
     transition: all 5s ease 0s;
  }
```

kindly share your answer to rectify the issue.

Comment: You did not implement anything, I dont beleive you

Comment: Use jsfiddle and show what you implemented!

Comment: What is there to transition? You are not changing the background image on hover at all.

Comment: Dear guys, kindly read my question once and rectify the issue. I have updated full details

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying an image url on hovered state. What should happen when you hover the image? Try it like this:

```
.service-image {
    background-image: url(yourimage.png);
    /* needs vendor prefix */
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
.service-image:hover {
    background-image: url(otherimage.png);
}
```

Comment: Hi , I have tried this one but this one is not working. kindly read my question once and rectify the issue. I have update detailed

Comment: Well firstly, I would put the transition on the element itself, else it will just apply the transition when entered, not when left. I have no idea why it wouldn't work in firefox.

Comment: yes, I got the same thing. But it will comes in chrome

Comment: Very strange behaviour, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think my query is not working in Mozilla.

Reason,
[https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052]

See the link and clarify the solution also.

Note:

My thought is using Font used then solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain conditions, [Summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) here. For `*:hover` you need to specify the path correctly.

**[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adBgRq/)** a complex branching trigger example.

### Here to your code which needs:

---

```
.list-colenter code here > a:hover > .service-image {
   background-image: url(yourimage.png);
   transition: all 5s ease 0s;
   /* transition is using statics */
}
.list-colenter code here > a:hover > .service-image {
   background-image: url(otherimage.png);
}
```

for

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-col">
        <a href="javascript:void();">
            <span class="service-image">&nbsp;</span>
            <h4>Pest control</h4>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```